# error al colocar link href enviando correo con smtp y php

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, smtp, php8

estoy intentando enviar un correo con php hacia Gmail mediante php, el correo me lo envía sin problema, mi detalle es que no me lee los estilos de las  Font que coloco mediante link href, no se si será que no se pueden  colocar así al enviar el correo, por que si coloco un tipo de letra en la hoja de estilos si me las lee, pero no me lee todo tipo de letras y eso también me deja pensativo, abajo coloco el código  que coloco al enviar el email, es pero que me puedan ayudar.

```
        


            $mail = new PHPMailer;
            //Configurar SMTP 
            $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Indicamos que use SMTP
            $mail->Host = '';  // Indicamos los servidores SMTP
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Habilitamos la autenticación SMTP
            $mail->Username = '';                 // SMTP username
            $mail->Password = '';                           // SMTP password
            $mail->SMTPSecure = '';                            // Habilitar encriptación TLS o SSL
            $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port
            
            // Configurar cabeceras del mensaje 
            $mail->From = '';                       // Correo del remitente
            $mail->FromName = $pag_web_nombre;           // Nombre del remitente
            $mail->Subject = $asunto;                // Asunto
            
            // Incluir destinatarios. El nombre es opcional 
            
                
            $mail->addAddress($correo);
                


        
            // Enviarlo en formato HTML 
            $mail->isHTML(true);                                  
    

            

            // Configurar cuerpo del mensaje 
            $mail->Body    = "

            <!DOCTYPE html>


            <html class='html_container'  lang='es'>
            <head>
            <title>$pag_web_nombre</title>  
            <meta charset='utf-8'>  
            <link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='https://www.dinervent.com/reme/imagenes/rve_32.png'>    
            
            <style>
            
            .correcto {
                border: 1px solid;
                margin: 10px 0px;
                padding:15px 10px 15px 0px;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: 10px center;
                font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size:13px;
                text-align:center;
                width:auto;
                border-radius: 20px;
            }
            .correcto {
                color: #000000;
                background-color: #00CD95;
            }
            
            .html_container{
            
                width: 100%; 
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
            
            }
            
            .body_container{
                max-width: 1000px;
                
            }
            
            
            .encabezado{
            
                width: $nombre_tamano_logo;
            }
            
            .container_email{
              
                background-color: $color_fondo;
                padding: 10px;
                border-radius: 20px;
                color: $color_texto;
                border: 1px solid;
                border-color: #000000;
            }
            
            .cont_msj{
            
                font-size: $nombre_tamano_texto_cont;
                font-family: $nombre_tip_letra_cont;
            }
            
            
            .titulo{
               font-family: $nombre_tip_letra_titulo;
                font-size: $nombre_tamano_texto_titulo;
            
            }
            
            .isotipo_codigo{
            
            width:  30px;
            height: 30px;
            
            }
            
            .link-social{
            
                cursor: pointer;
                padding: 3px;
            
            }
            
            .coletilla{
            
                font-size:10px;
            
            }
            
            
            
            .direccion{
            
            font-size: $nombre_tamano_texto_direc;
            
            }
            
            .venta_dinervent{
            
            border-radius: 20px; 
            width: auto;
            width: $nombre_tamano_img;
            }
            
            

            
            
            .button {
              display: inline-block;
              background-color: $color_boton;
              border: none;
              color: $color_texto_boton;
              text-align: center;
              font-size: 20px;
              padding: 15px;
              width: $nombre_tamano_map;
              transition: all 0.5s;
              cursor: pointer;
              margin: 5px;
              border-radius: 8px;
              border: 1px solid;
                border-color: #000000;
              
            }
            .button span {
              cursor: pointer;
              display: inline-block;
              position: relative;
              transition: 0.5s;
            }
            
            .button:hover {
              padding-right: 25px;
            }
            .button:hover {
              opacity: 1;
              right: 0;
              background-color: $color_hover_boton;
            }
                
            
                </style>

                <body class='body_container'>
          
                <div class='container_email'>
                <div  align='center'><a target='_blank' href='https://www.dinervent.com/$pag_web/'><img src='https://www.dinervent.com/reme/foto_locales/$logo_empresa' class='encabezado'  alt='$pag_web_nombre' title='$pag_web_nombre'></a></div>
             
                <br><br><br>
                <div  align='center' class='titulo'>$asunto<br></div>
               
                <br><br>
                
                $promocion_act
              
                <br><br>
                <div align='center' class='cont_msj'>$mensaje</div> 
           
                
    <br><br>
                <div align='center'><a target='_blank' href='https://www.dinervent.com/$pag_web/'><button class='button'>ir a $pag_web_nombre</button></a></div>
                <br>           
    
             
            <br>
            $direccion_act
              
    <div align='center'><div class='coletilla'><br><br>Este correo es de caracter publicitario, no se solicitara ningun tipo de informacion por esta via,  en caso de que se le solicite informacion de algun tipo, lo podra denunciar por la pagina <a  target='_blank' title='Dinervent'  href='https://www.dinervent.com/reme/market.php'>www.dinervent.com</a><br><br></div></div>
  
          </div>  
       
                </body>
 
    </head>
    </html>
 
            
            
";
            $mail->AltBody = 'Este es el mansaje en texto plano para clientes que no admitan HTML';
            
            // Para que use el lenguaje español 
            $mail->setLanguage('es');
            
            // Enviar mensaje... 
            if(!$mail->send()) {
                
                echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            } else {
            
            }
```

y si me pueden aclarar si no todos los tipos de fuentes son aceptados al enviar un correo con hoja de estilo o estoy si estoy haciendo algo mal

Comment: Quizás lo que no lee son las clases para los estilos, prueba poniendo estilos directo en tu HTML -> `style="..."`

Comment: Tienes que agregar `headers` en tu función `mail()` indicando que es contenido html. [Ejemplos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469300/php-mail-not-sending-styles)

Comment: No podrás enviar un email con estilos definidos aparte en un archivo `.css` (práctica recomendada para sitios web), porque muchos clientes de correo no admiten archivos `.css` sobre todo por cuestiones de seguridad. Tienes que poner los estilos in-line, es decir, en cada elemento y declarar, como ya te han dicho, que el email es de tipo `html`.

Comment: los correos no muestran fuentes desconocidas, eso no se puede hacer

Comment: ok, ya agregue el código completo, cuando coloco  $mail->isHTML(true); ya estoy declarando que es html no? incluso todo el formato llega como html sin problema, mi problema era que no reconoce algunas fuentes que coloco,  ya vi que no puedo llamar fuentes externas entonces las estoy declarando en el mismo html